# Subscribing with $geoWithin returns empty array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

Everytime I try to return some data from a collection it returns an empty array. I'm using iron router and this is my code:

Client:

```
Meteor.call('insertEvent', {
    "eventLoc": {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates": [ 
            eventLongitude, 
            eventLatitude
        ]}
}

function getBox() {
var bounds = GoogleMaps.maps.mapSeek.instance.getBounds();
var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
    Session.set('box', [[sw.lat(),sw.lng()],[ne.lat(),ne.lng()]]);
}

getbox();
```

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('publicPlaces', function(box) {
var find = {
    eventLoc: {
        $geoWithin: {
            $box: box
        }
    }
};

return Events.find(find);
});
```

Routes:

```
Router.route('/seek', function () {
  this.render('seek');
  Meteor.subscribe('publicPlaces', Session.get('box'));
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the error is in your `box` value. According to MongoDB manual you have to specify longitude first, and the code `Session.set('box', [[sw.lat(),sw.lng()],[ne.lat(),ne.lng()]]);` seems to do conversely.

Comment: Ofcourse, gah Im so angry at myself for missing that.

Thank you